# Passing a modified *args to base class in python

Tags: python, inheritance, args

Suppose you have

```
class Block:
  def __init__(self, *args):   
    ...
```

which you might call with `Block("resource", "some", { "other": "args}`)

and then you want to make a

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, *args):    
        <SOMETHING HERE calling Block passing "resource" as the first arg>
```

so that you can write

`Resource("some", { "other": "args})`

and have it do the same thing as

`Block("resource", "some", { "other": "args}`

What does the `<SOMETHING HERE ...>` line look like?

Comment: So you want to create a `Resource` instance and call `Block` with it and other passed params?

Comment: I would have expected `class Resource(Block):`

Comment: You mean `super()`?

Comment: I want to pass `"resource"` and the args to Resource to the Block ctor

Comment: When you say "resource" do you mean a string or the particular instance of `Resource` that's being initialized? And where you have `*args` do you mean `**kwargs`, given that `{"other":"args"}` is a dictionary?

Comment: `Block('resource', *args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have an *"is a"* relationship here, which is properly modeled by inheritance. I would recommend one of two approaches.

1. If a `Resource` *is a* `Block`, then call it out as such

```py
class Resource(Block):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__("resource", *args)
```

2. If a `Resource` is not a `Block`, then create an alternate constructor for `Block`

```py
class Block:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # instantiate however

    @classmethod
    def make_resource(cls, *args):
        return cls('resource', *args)
```

Comment: Thanks, that first answer is what I was looking for